# Cleartool difference between -element and -version

Tags: version-control, clearcase, cleartool

When searching for a way to find all files in a clearcase repo that changed since date X i found two approaches

`cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype(abranch)" -element "{created_since(10-Jan)}" -print`

as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785791/how-to-find-files-in-a-given-branch)

and

`cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype(abranch)" -version "created_since(10-Jan)" -print`

as (though modified to resemble the same branch) found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300632/cleartool-finding-changes-from-specific-date)

What is the difference between the created_since filter in -version and -element? The results do differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "[ClearTool: Finding changes from specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22300947/6309)", I had to use `-version` in order to check for updated directories and detect *deleted* files.

But in "[how to find files in a given branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2786120/6309)", since the search is limited to files, I only had to check for files "created" (added to source control, hence the `-element`) since a certain date. I didn't have to check to modification in that question.

The [`cleartool find`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm?lang=en) allows to filter on:

> - `-element`: Selects element objects using a VOB query; all of the selected element's branches and versions are also selected.
>     Using this option with a `brtype` query makes `find -all` much faster in a large VOB where the specified branch type exists on a relatively small number of elements.

Note: I used the `find + -ele brtype` approach in "[find files in clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1311665/6309)" or "[UCM-Clearcase - How to find new undelivered files for a given “stream”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5167005/6309)".

> - `-version`: From the set of objects that survived the element-level and branch-level queries (if any), selects version objects using a VOB query.